# Creating existing android project to import support library 7 gets errors right away

Tags: android

I imported the supportv7app library as a existing android project, followed the official docs step by step and get errors right off the bat. I get 3, all in resources folder, 2 were regarding a color not existing and another involving a linear layout not using an orientation, how does this even happen when the support library comes straight from the sdk tools

These are not the big issue, the issue is when I reference the library from my main application, my strings.xml throws an error saying its not translated in a bunch of different languages, probably from the support library. I found over 5 guides all followed them step by step and I can't google the answer, I feel I may be alone in this, but I didn't do anything out of the ordinary to cause issues. I even redownloaded the support library

edit: I found a way to ignore the errors and compile, but I get a resource not found when setting my theme to Theme.AppCombat.Light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might looking for ShelockActionBar ;-)

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, can you tell me what I gain or lose from using this over the support library? I read it is an extension, so it is the same thing but maybe easier to use? I am also doing this to learn so I would try not to abstract everything

Comment: @CatznDogz AFAIK the original `action bar` isn't available in support library, the above library is ported version of `action bar` for lower API and It's same to  the original one.